# asymptotics for coefficients of generating functions involving logarithms

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

I have a generating function that has a closed form like $1/(\log(z-a)+b)$ and I would like to get asymptotics for the size of the coefficients of it.

I was going to use the methods in Chapter 5 of Wilf's Generatingfunctionology using the singularities. However, there is a branch point of log(z-a) at z=a. In Section 5.3 of Wilf's book, he discusses how to handle algebraic singularities (e.g., the branch point at $z=1$ of $\sqrt{z-1}$, but I have not been able to find anything about how to handle branch points when the function is transcendental (like the log function that I am considering).

Are there any known techniques for handling the branch points of such functions?
If so, would anyone have references they could provide on this, please?

Answer (score 6):

See Chapter VI of Flajolet and Sedgewick, Analytic combinatorics, Cambridge 2009.

Answer (score 2):

That method described in the book by Flajolet & Sedgewick is implemented in a Maple function "equivalent" of the Algolib library that you can download from http://algo.inria.fr/libraries/ . The code is not maintained any more, but still works in your example:

> equivalent(1/(log(a-z)+b),z,n) assuming a>0;

$$\frac{a^{-n}}{n\log^2n}\left(1+O\left(\frac1{\log n}\right)\right),$$
(this is a slightly simplified form of the actual output). Note that compared with your initial question, I've changed log(z-a) into log(a-z) which makes more sense for a generating function.

Answer (score 0):

see also

P. Flajolet & A. Odlyzko,
"Singularity analysis of generating functions"
*Siam. J. Disc. Math.* **3** (1990) 216--240